# Search Bar click detect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I have a search bar and i want to detect when the user click it , and after to disable a button while the user is editing in search bar.  How can i do this , because i was trying to do wha you will see above but it's never called.

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
        NSLog(@"yes");
    }
```

Other methods like `searchDisplayController` are called.I set also

```
self.searchBar.delegate=self
```

but no result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can directly use the delegate of the UIsearchbar for getting the click event. you can use this delegate for it for checking the click. and for getting end editing this second one.

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    NSLog(@"Yes");
    return YES;
}
```

End Editing

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift version of the answer:

1. Add **UISearchBarDelegate** to your view controller Assign its
2. delegate to self **searchBar.delegate = self** Use
3. **searchBarShouldEndEditing** or **searchBarSearchButtonClicked**

   ```
    func searchBarShouldEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
      return true
   }
   ```

or

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:` method is called when the user taps the "Search" (return) button on the keyboard. From you question, I understand that you want to detect when the user taps the search bar, to enter text for the search. If that's the case, you need to implement the `searchBarShouldBeginEditing:` or `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:` methods in the UISearchBarDelegate.
For example,

```
-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    NSLog(@"yes");
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: oh, yeah, you're right. Sorry, my mistake, that method actually should return a BOOL. I've edited my answer. The method needs to return YES for the textField to become first responder.