# UISearchBarDelegate function -searchBarSearchButtonClicked not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use a delegate function searchBarSearchButtonClicked from UISearchBarDelegate.  My search bar is located in the header of UITableViewController.  Please can someone advise?

```
 class MySearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate{


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    print("clicked!")
}
```

}

Comment: "not working" is not a proper error description, did you hook up the class as delegate for a searchbar?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154955/search-bar-click-detect

Comment: add `seachBar.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the delegate of search bar.

**(1)** `mySearchBar.delegate = self`

**(2)** In storyboard, **ctrl+drag** the search bar to the viewController and choosing delegate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please take outlet for your searchbar and confirm delegate.

```
yoursearchbar.delegate = self
```

Thanks